# RMarkdown: Change fonts when generating PDFs?

Tags: fonts, latex, r-markdown, tinytex

I'm new to the RMarkdown >> LaTeX >> PDF pipeline. I'm trying to change the fonts in my final PDF, but I don't know what package to install for any given font. [This post](https://babichmorrowc.github.io/post/changing-fonts-in-rmarkdown-pdfs/) works for changing the font to Source Sans Pro, but I don't know what package to install for any other fonts.

I'm using TinyTeX as my LaTeX distribution, which according to [documentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/latex-variables.html) is supposed to install packages automatically.

My first attempt was to simply name a different font as my mainfont in the YAML header, e.g. [Bera Sans](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/berasans/), which is included in the LaTeX font catalogue, and let TinyTeX worry about the rest.

```
---
title: "example"
output:
  pdf_document:
    includes:
        in_header: "header.tex"
mainfont: BeraSans
---
```

However, here, nothing happens and the default RMarkdown font gets used instead.

My second attempt was to follow the usage instructions for Bera Sans, linked above, and add "\usepackage[scaled]{berasans}" to my header.tex file as below.

```
\usepackage[scaled]{berasans}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\newcommand{\blandscape}{\begin{landscape}}
\newcommand{\elandscape}{\end{landscape}}
```

Again, this results in the default RMarkdown font.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that I need different LaTeX commands if I want a serif font to be my default font. I didn't think I needed to add `\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}`, but turns out it was necessary.

Currently, my PDF is being written in Bera Sans with the following header.tex:

```latex
\usepackage[scaled]{berasans}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\newcommand{\blandscape}{\begin{landscape}}
\newcommand{\elandscape}{\end{landscape}}
```